# c# to automatically populate the data in combo box

Tags: c#

I am having a drop down box which get automatically populated with the database list on the click of a button. What I have tried to achieve with the below code is that if the user select master database, then it should automatically select "master.sql" file from the specified location.and if the user has selected some other database from the list, the it should select "dbscript.sql" file from the specified location.

But what I get as output is even if I select master database, the combo box is getting populated with "dbscript.sql".

Can anyone point out what mistake I am doing here?

C# Code:

```
string sel = comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();
if (sel != "master")
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Testpgm");
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("dbscript.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
else
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Testpgm");
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("master.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Updated Issue:

[image]
Any comments would be really appreciated..

Comment: Place a breakpoint in your code and see what's the value of `comboBox1.SelectedText`. Probably you'll want to use `comboBox1.SelectedItem` or `comboBox1.Text` instead.

Comment: check the text in sel during debugging

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: Placed breakpoint and could find that the control is not going to else part.

Comment: Yes, because it's always `""`, isnt't it? You don't actually select the text inside the `ComboBox`, you only change the selected item. Check my answer below.

Comment: You should use SelectedItem instead of SelectedText as there are some issues with SelectedText as stated on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.100).aspx): However, you should be aware that the selection can change automatically because of user interaction. For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.

Comment: @Macro: Tried yours..But no luck again..

Comment: Wich items are in comboBox1?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: Retrieved databases are populated in combobox 1.
Now it is like I actually got the correct file when I select master database. But each time I select other database from the combo box I am getting more lengthier list,even though I am having only 2 files namely "master.sql" and "dbscript.sql". Please see my update in my question.

Comment: But you clear the comboBox2 before add the files?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: I use the code above. and please see my updated post.

Comment: I think you have to clear comboBox2 prior to add results:

    comboBox2.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ComboBox.SelectedText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx):

> Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a
>   ComboBox.

Probably what you will need to use is the `comboBox1.SelectedItem` or `comboBox1.Text` properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason here can be that your statement

```
if (sel != "master")
```

is always false. Which means that sel is never equal to master. You need to debug is this really == master?

Comment: I tried your approach earlier..But could view the same issue..After that I changed to present code and tried..

Comment: what is the value of sel?  can you please post it here>

Comment: Whatever the user selects in the combo box, that value is sel. Atleast I am assuming to be so in my code..

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug what comboBox1.SelectedText actually is.
I think it might contain a different spelling of "master", maybe upper case.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx:

You can use the SelectedText property to retrieve or change the currently selected text in a ComboBox control. However, you should be aware that the selection can change automatically because of user interaction. For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.

When the combo box loses focus, the selection point moves to the beginning of the text and any selected text becomes unselected. In this case, getting the SelectedText property retrieves an empty string, and setting the SelectedText property adds the specified value to the beginning of the text.